# Vue Array Prop JSDoc TypeScript error in VS Code: Type 'ArrayConstructor' is missing the following properties from type 'MyCustomType[]'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

Inspired by the "Type checking with JSDoc" section on "[Why I no longer use TypeScript with React and why you might want to switch too](https://hackernoon.com/why-i-no-longer-use-typescript-with-react-and-why-you-shouldnt-either-e744d27452b4#7fa9)", I'm using a Vue CLI created project with ES6 but no TypeScript compilation or TypeScript code.

I turned on the "**Check JS**" setting in Visual Studio Code which allows you to type check your JS files as if they were TypeScript. Type checking is "enabled" for Visual Studio Code via JSDoc / @type comments.  I use the following to put my JS code in a separate file from my Vue code:

```
<script src="./MyComponent.js"></script>
```

If I try to set the type for an Array prop on a component like this:
MyComponent.js

```
 /**
 * @typedef {object} MyCustomType
 * @property {number} myNumberField
 */

export default {
  props: {
    /** @type {Array<MyCustomType>} */
    resultCards: Array
  }
};
```

I am getting the following Problem (red underlines) in Visual Studio Code:

```
Type 'ArrayConstructor' is missing the following properties 
from type 'MyCustomType[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 25 more.ts(2740)
```

Does anyone know of a solution for this? I would like to keep my code as JavaScript so I don't have to convert the project to TypeScript to gain type checking. If there's no solution, I may just ignore trying to actually set types for Vue props members.

See also: [Microsoft/TypeScript: JSDoc support in JavaScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JSDoc-support-in-JavaScript)

Edit: If was using TypeScript with Vue, I think the following link would have the answer: but I'm trying to use plain JavaScript and JSDoc and then use type checks from VSCode.

from https://frontendsociety.com/using-a-typescript-interfaces-and-types-as-a-prop-type-in-vuejs-508ab3f83480

> cast the Object as a function that returns the interface, like this:

```
props: {   testProp: Object as () => { test: boolean } }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searched some more and this time I found the answer here: https://blog.usejournal.com/type-vue-without-typescript-b2b49210f0b

I needed to change my snippet above to:

```
export default {
  props: {
    /** @type {{ new (): MyCustomType[] }} */
    resultCards: Array
  }
};
```

Another syntax that also works (which I like better) is:

```
export default {
  props: {
    /** @type {{ new (): Array<MyCustomType> }} */
    resultCards: Array
  }
};
```

Comment: Dont work with PyCharm or eslint-plugin-jsdoc